# Most recent post from another database

Tags: posts, loop, database, footer

I am trying to add the most recent post from another Wordpress database (on the same server in all actuality), but am getting the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method wpdb::query_posts() in /var/www/site/wp-content/themes/custom/footer.php on line 68`

Here is the code:

```
<!-- .entry-content -->
<?php
$originaldb = new wpdb('username', 'password', 'db', 'localhost');
$originaldb->query_posts( 'posts_per_page=1' );  
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

<header class="entry-header">
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php echo '<span class="entry-day">'.get_the_date('j').'</span><br><span class="entry-month">'.get_the_date('M').'</span>'; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="title-box">
            <h2 class="blog-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
            <?php echo '<a href="'.get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ).'">' . the_author() . '</a>'; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </header>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>  
Testing has failed
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wordpress wpdb class is a little different than the normal way of querying in that you run "vanilla" database queries.

You can see documentation on the wpdb class on the Wordpress docs: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database

Also, in regard to your code, you should be able to change the line here:

```
$originaldb->query_posts( 'posts_per_page=1' );
```

To something like this:

```
$results = $originaldb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts LIMIT 1" );
```

This will provide you with an array of posts that you can then process with a loop:

```
if($results):
  foreach($results as $post): setup_postdata($post); 
    // do stuff with normal wp template tags
  endforeach;
else: 
  // no posts 
endif;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_other_posts() {
    $wpdb_old = wp_clone( $GLOBALS['wpdb'] );
    $wpdb_new = &$GLOBALS['wpdb'];  

    // All you have to care about following two lines
    $wpdb_new = new wpdb( 'your_db_username', 'db_password', 'new_db_name', 'localhost' );
    $wpdb_new->set_prefix( 'wp_' );

    // Now whatever function you'll call, it will use new database
    $posts = get_posts( 'numberposts=5' );

    // We are done so lets take the old wpdb back on its position
    $wpdb_new = $wpdb_old;  
}
```